# Create convex hull with array of points in opencv.js

Tags: javascript, opencv

Im trying to create a convex hull with opencv.js based on an array with points, does anyone know a way to do this correctly and efficient? An array would look like this:

```
[
    [5,5],
    [10,10],
    [15,15]
    ...
]
```

-> where the first value would be the `x` and the second the `y` value, but it wouldn't be a problem to change this format to something more suitable.

Thnx for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

As far I could experiment OpenCV stores contour/hull data in `Mat` format with type `CV_32SC2`: essentially a flat list of 32bit short integers in `[x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,...]` order.

Note the two channels/planes part of 32S**C2**: one channel for all the x values and another for all the y values

You can manually create such a `Mat`, access it's `data32S` property and fill in each value:

```
let testHull = cv.Mat.ones(4, 1, cv.CV_32SC2);
testHull.data32S[0] = 100;
testHull.data32S[1] = 100;
testHull.data32S[2] = 200;
testHull.data32S[3] = 100;
testHull.data32S[4] = 200;
testHull.data32S[5] = 200;
testHull.data32S[6] = 100;
testHull.data32S[7] = 200;
```

However OpenCV.js comes with a handy method to convert a flat array of values to such a Mat:

```
let testHull = cv.matFromArray(4, 1, cv.CV_32SC2, [100,100,200,100,200,200,100,200])
```

If your array is nested, you can simply use JS Array's [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method to flatten it from a 2D array(`[[x1,y1]...]`) to a 1D array (`[x1,y1,...]`).

So you don't have to worry about the `Mat` type and all that you can wrap it all into a nice function, for example:

```js
function nestedPointsArrayToMat(points){
   return cv.matFromArray(points.length, 1, cv.CV_32SC2, points.flat());
}
```

Here's a quick demo:

```js
function onOpenCvReady(){
  cv.then(test);
}

function nestedPointsArrayToMat(points){
   return cv.matFromArray(points.length, 1, cv.CV_32SC2, points.flat());
}

function test(cv){
  

  console.log("cv loaded");
  // make a Mat to draw into
  let mainMat = cv.Mat.zeros(30, 30, cv.CV_8UC3);
  // make a fake hull
  let points = [
                  [ 5, 5],
                  [25, 5],
                  [25,25],
                  [ 5,25]
                ]
  let hull = nestedPointsArrayToMat(points);
  console.log("hull data", hull.data32S);
  // make a fake hulls vector 
  let hulls = new cv.MatVector();
  // add the recently created hull
  hulls.push_back(hull);
  // test drawing it
  cv.drawContours(mainMat, hulls, 0, [192,64,0,0], -1, 8);
  // output to canvas
  cv.imshow('canvasOutput', mainMat);  
}
```

```html
<script async src="https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/opencv.js" onload="onOpenCvReady();" type="text/javascript"></script>
<canvas id="canvasOutput" width="30" height="30"></canvas>
```

Note that the above is a rough example, there's no data validation or any other fancier checks, but hopefully it illustrates the idea so it can be extended robustly as required.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say that your points represent a contour:

```
var contours = new cv.MatVector();
for (var i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
   contours.push_back(new cv.Mat(points[i][0], points[i][1])
}
```

Now following [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/dc/dcf/tutorial_js_contour_features.html) from opencv website:

```
// approximates each contour to convex hull
for (var i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i) {
    var tmp = new cv.Mat();
    var cnt = contours.get(i);
    // You can try more different parameters
    cv.convexHull(cnt, tmp, false, true);
    hull.push_back(tmp);
    cnt.delete(); tmp.delete();
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the fast response :) I tried the code above but i have problems with the first part where you try to make a new cv.Mat with a point. My code keeps returning: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'width' in 741.

Comment: I see the same issue as above.